# Why do I see the weird backspace behaviour on my shell sometimes?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, backspace

I use bash shell and sometimes all of a sudded, my <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key stops working (when this happens <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> still works fine)

I am not sure why this happens, but it also carries over to any vim sessions that I use from the shell. To my surprise, getting a fresh shell does not help, and the problem seems to go away as abruptly as it started.

This is what the typed characters look like, each <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keypress is shown by a `^?` on the shell

```
$ cat filem^?namr^?e
```

Does anybody have a clue what might be happening? How can I restore the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in the shell

```
stty erase ^?
```

If that works for you, add it to one of your startup/profile scripts.

Much more detail on this can be found here - 
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html

Comment: this works! can you please explain what is happening? Also, why is the issue intermittent?

Comment: I don't know why it would happen during a session? are you loading other configurations during the session? Or does the problem occur after running a particular piece of software?

Comment: Ohh I see.. the problem always starts/ends when I switch using/not using VPN.